# orion context broker delete several entities at one call

Tags: database, fiware, fiware-orion

I want to DELETE all entities /v2/entities?type=person
I do not want do it one by one.

In SQL it will look like

> DELETE from person

Currently I can delete only one entity per call with this: DELETE /v2/entities/{id}?type={entityType}

How to delete everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [batch update](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#batch-operations) to delete several entities at the same time. However, you need to know the particular entity ids to delete.

Deteling all the entities of a given type is not currently supported in the Orion API, but it is in our roadmap. If you are interested in this functionality and what to show your support, please give it a +1 to [the github issue about it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1645).

As workaround if you have access to the MongoDB instance used by Orion you can do the following operation to remove all entities of a given type (assuming you are using `orion` as DB):

```
echo 'db.entities.remove({"_id.type": "Person"})' | mongo orion --quiet
```

**EDIT:** the following script can be useful to delete all entities (of a given type and/or matching a given filter) at Orion through the NGSIv2 API (i.e. no need to have access to DB directly).

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/utils/delete_entities.py

Use it with care ;)

Comment: Added information about how to remove all entities using a script through NGSIv2 API